# How do I customize my log out warning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm using the following code for my logout:

```
<%= link_to "log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :destroy, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to log out?"} %>
```

But the standard confirmation prompt is pretty ugly. How can I customize this?

Any help here would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The standard customization pops up an "alert" box. And you cannot style the alert box. But you could use a modal with bootstrap or jquery and have a `javascript` that triggers the modal
 `onclick`.

Using jquery-ujs would be easy, you just have to

`$.rails.confirm = function(message) { return myConfirmDialog(message); };`

See this [article](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-jquery-ujs-now-interactive/) for implementation.

And if it doesn't work, then you need to override the rails.allowAction.

```
$.rails.allowAction = function(link) {
  if (!link.attr('data-confirm')) {
    return true;
  }
  $.rails.showConfirmDialog(link);
  return false;
};

$.rails.confirmed = function(link) {
  link.removeAttr('data-confirm');
  return link.trigger('click.rails');
};

$.rails.showConfirmDialog = function(link) {
  var html;
  html = "<div id='dialog-confirm' title='Are you sure you want to delete?'></div>";
  return $(html).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      OK: function() {
        $.rails.confirmed(link);
        return $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        return $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Assuming you use jQueryUI. If using Bootstrap try this [gist](https://gist.github.com/seyhunak/3977007), (its coffeescript, but you can re-write in JS)

===================================================================

Regarding the styling question, if you are using rails 4* then you need to require the jquery-ui modules.

like : 
    `//= require jquery.ui.all`

and

```
/*
 *= require jquery.ui.core
 *= require jquery.ui.theme
 */
```

in application.js and application.css respectively. More details [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jquery-ui-rails/4.1.1/frames).

If you are using 3.1 , then you perhaps need the jquery-rails and jquery-ui-rails in your `Gemfile`, Its not supposed to show a blank dialog, since I used the [jquery-ui-dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) syntax.

If still its blank (which it is not supposed to be) you can add a little css to `#dialog-confirm` , try to debug, see if the modal is jquery-ui's and perhaps you don't have the stylesheets.

Comment: Cheers! This seems to work, however, the box itself is transparent. Is there any styling for this particular pop-up? If you can share some styling a long with your JS I will accept your answer. Thanks!